# TFS - How to identify obsolete build defintions

Tags: tfs, obsolete, resource-cleanup, build-definition

We are support project across our companies.

We are going to have around 100 projects, 3 build definitions per project, around 5-7 branches and their build definitions.

Now as development of branch is completed, build definition(s) of that branch is of no use.

To optimize the disk usage, we would like to implement weekly job which checks obsolete build definitions and then run a clean up command.

Is there any way we can implement the same? 
or 
any tool available from Microsoft?

Comment: I don't think there is any tool available to list obsolete build definitions. As so many different scenarios can be considered as obsolete, I think your team also have a clear definition about what kind of build is obsolete.

Comment: @manishjoisar What would make a build definition obsolete in your situation? Time (build definitions older than n months should be automatically deleted)? Any other condition?

Comment: We were also working on the same to come up with conditions, but now i got option from CodePlex to get list of build definition with last execution. https://teamprojectmanager.codeplex.com/ . Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any tool available to list obsolete build definitions, because there are so many different scenarios can be considered as obsolete. I think your team also have a clear definition about what kind of build is obsolete which different from others. Maybe you can work with TFS API to add your own obsolete logic, then destroy these obsolete via code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as of now we do not have any scenarios to consider build definition as obsolete, so i am also looking for scenarios too.